# null thread identifier [WinAPI] (not thread handle)

Tags: winapi

Let's say I keep DWORD thread_Id in some structure (WinAPI) .
(I am asking about thread_ID not thread_handle in this question. Indeed it is easy to confure the two)

I need to initialize threadId variable to some some null value.

So I am going to define my NULL_THREAD_ID value.

Is it documented anywhere on msdn which DWORD value real thread can never have as thread_ID ? 0 or (DWORD)-1 ?

```
   HANDLE WINAPI CreateThread(
     __in_opt   LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
     __in       SIZE_T dwStackSize,
     __in       LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
     __in_opt   LPVOID lpParameter,
     __in       DWORD dwCreationFlags,
     __out_opt  LPDWORD lpThreadId
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`GetThreadId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683233%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), for example, gives you the answer to the puzzle.  It returns the thread ID and the documentation states:

> If the function fails, the return value is zero.

Therefore, zero can never be a valid thread ID.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: check at [`CreateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

*If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the new thread.*

*If the function fails, the return value is NULL.*

And NULL = 0.

[Update:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686746%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) *Note that no thread identifier will ever be 0.*

Comment: added distinction about thread ID vs thread hande to the question. About handles, you are right, handle can be initializedeither to NULL or to (HANDLE)-1 (aka INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE).I am asking about thread ID which are of type DWORD.